# Network sharing using AFP command line: mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 2, errno is 2

Tags: network, afp

I have a server with some directories exported for AFP.  I can mount afp volumes from Finder without any problem.

When I try this from the command line:

```
$ sudo mount_afp  'afp://me:mypass@my-server/home/me'  /Users/me/myMountPoint
```

I get the error 
`mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 2, errno is 2`

As stated, I can mount my-server's `/home/me` using Finder and my credentials on that machine just fine.   Also tried with `mount_afp -i ...` interactive mode with no luck.

apparently, error 2 is:

```
error 2 siInitVBLQsErr: VBLqueues for all slots could not be initialized. or dsAddressErr: address error
```

Which doesn't help much

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `/home/me` wasn't the share name on my-server - just the local path.   It is actually "me's home".  I went in to the server and changed that behavior in /etc/afp.conf

Comment: How did you change that?